# How to find user-based and item-based collaborative filter of given dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I am quite new in this data mining field and just trying to learn it. Below is my dataset.

[DataSet](https://github.com/jayudhandha/DataSets/blob/master/Courses.csv)

It contains Data of Courses vs Students. Every student has gave there rating based on chooses course.

Now for (E N) I want to do 2 things.

1. Considering a user-based collaborative filter find which students is possible to compute correlations with E.N?
2. Considering a item-based collaborative filtering, Suggest a suitable Course to (E N)

Below is my code

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

ratings = pd.read_csv('Courses.csv',index_col=0)
ratings = ratings.fillna(0)
ratings

trainset, testset = train_test_split(ratings , test_size=.25, random_state=1)
# Above line is not good, As i need to convert the ratings into DataFrame or read this csv as DataFrame
## User-based filtering
sim_options = {'name': 'cosine', 'user_based': True}
algo = KNNBasic(sim_options=sim_options)

ratings_similarity = cosine_similarity(ratings.T)

ratings_similarity_df=pd.DataFrame(ratings_similarity,index=ratings.columns,columns=ratings.columns)


print(ratings_similarity_df)
```

It will be great if someone can help to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: What *exactly* is your issue and your question?

Comment: From the given dataSet, I want implement the user-base and item-based collaborative filtering to suggest a Course to a student whose name is (E N). But i am stuck at a point, I have attached the code which i wrote. Now i need someone's help who can guide me further!